# Prompt user to enter 3 numbers, add the 2 highest numbers (Cannot call method)

Tags: java

I'm trying to prompt the user to enter 3 numbers. After those numbers are entered, I am to add the highest two numbers. The main method is to handle all print statements and is to call the other method. I'm not allowed to use for loop for this problem. The variables from the main, should be passed down to the other method.

I am not sure why I am unable to call the method from the main. Here is my code:

```
public class HW {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner console = new  Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter three numbers.");

        int x = console.nextInt();
        int y = console.nextInt();
        int z = console.nextInt();

         HW.calLargestSum(); //ERROR
         HW.calLargestSum(int x, int y, int z); //STILL ERROR   
    }

    public int calLargestSum(int x, int y, int z){

        if ( x > y && x > z && y > z )    
          return  x + y;

        else if ( y > x && y > z && x > z )
         return y + x;

      else if ( z > x && z > y && y > x )
         return z + y;

        return 0;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Next time you ask questions about compilation errors, **please** post the error message and indicate the line that causes it. Else you force folks to guess, and that's not playing nice here.

Comment: I'm intrigued: why did you accept my answer, then the other posters answer, to finally unaccept both?

Comment: @Function  I was trying to accept both. When I pressed the refresh button, my computer did something weird.

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem

You are making some mistakes when calling the method from main. The non-trivial mistake is that you can't call non-static from `static`. This happens because if it is not `static` then it is an instance method. Thus, it requires an instance to access it.

---

#### Static Solution

Make your method static. So change your method to:

```
public static int calLargestSum(int x, int y, int z)
{ ... }
```

To call the method, you can use:

```
calLargestSum(1,2,3); 
// or in your case.
calLargestSum(x,y,z);
```

---

#### Instance Solution

The other option is to make a new instance of your class (if you don't want it to use static). Like so:

```
HW hwObj = new HW();
```

To call use this:

```
hwObj.calLargestSum(1,2,3);
```

---

#### To See Returned Value/Print

```
 int largest = calLargestSum(x, y, z); 
 System.out.println(largest);
```

Comment: Don't forget to address the problem in the line that calls the method.

Comment: thanks for answering. is there an obvious reason why my code isn't actually adding the highest two numbers or is my code completely wrong? it's just printing out the numbers that the user inputs.

Comment: @sfvgsvegsfsgsfgs Look at my new edit. You need to store the return value in a variable then print it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call it because you have not instantiated an HW object.  Two solutions:

```
HW hw = new HW();
hw.calLargestSum();
```

Or make the method static, so that you don't need to instantiate it:

```
public static int calLargetSum();
```

Further... ok, so many problems...

```
HW.calLargestSum(); //ERROR
```

There is no method `calLargestSum()`, there is only `calLargestSum(int x, int y, int z)`.

```
HW.calLargestSum(int x, int y, int z); //STILL ERROR
```

You need to pass values here.  `int x` is not a value.  You need to pass values like:

```
HW.calLargestSum(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: Don't forget to address the problem in the line that calls the method.

Comment: thanks. i thought using int x would allow me to pass the values that the user inputs. i didn't want to fix value right away.